# How to use Union Type as Contraint in Generaic type parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

It seems it is impossible to have a generic class which is constraint by a union type. Basically this:

```
class Shoe {
    constructor(public size: number){}
}

class Dress {
    constructor(public style: string){}
}

class Box <T extends Shoe | Dress > {
}
```

Then this:

```
// because move can move multiple boxes of Box of shoes or Box of dress
class Move<B extends Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]> {
    private stuff: B;
    constructor(public toMove: Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]) {
        this.stuff = toMove // this does not compile
    }

}
```

Or how can this be achieved? I have a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAWB7AptA3gKGt6xEDsIAXAJwFdgjESAKABzICMQBLYaCFgL2QC5p8ZALaNkJAJRoAvhhkZQkGABESyKOiw48hUhSq0GzNhyIBPEHxMkW+AOaSZcheoBCiAB7QAPABVoydyJkfAATGAQUaAAfaBU1GAA+DTkMAHpU6FFgMDIIVCFEADdUbPxoAuLyshAiFjoLTI81aEQAM2g3TzaOJGbqDo8W9pDVKHlwdQBZIuQvF39A4LCB9y8I5ASAbQBdaJWvOKgt7aTMHGg6a0KwIJMyVtb+FwBuTWxtYnJKanomVnYqNNik8PGtesc9p0DqMIMdxBpzuciPAWBAAHTEe7tAC80EBMze0DkMiAA) demonstrating the situation

Comment: Props for sharing a playground link, not many people share a MWE when asking questions.

Comment: Apart from the `stuff` not being an array (most likely minor typo) you should probably let the constructor have the following signature: `constructor(public toMove: B[])`

Comment: Reason being that you initially restricted `B` to be either but not the other while your proposed constructor would accept either without restriction hence the incompatibility.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Thanks for spotting the typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic are you saying what I want to model is impossible? Have a generic class with its type parameters constrained by union type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, and again it is a guess of your true intent, this should suffice:

```
class Shoe {
    constructor(public size: number){}
}

class Dress {
    constructor(public style: string){}
}

class Box <T extends Shoe | Dress > {
}


// because move can move multiple boxes of Box of shoes or Box of dress
class Move<B extends Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]> {
    private stuff: B;
    constructor(public toMove: B) {
        this.stuff = toMove;
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't work as `Box<Shoe | Dress>[]` is fundamentally different from `Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]`

Comment: Ok, "B extends Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]" it is. Fundamental problem is in parameter passed to the constructor. You cannot downcast it from B to what B extends.